# regex to print lines if value between patterns is greater than number - solution which is independent of column position

Tags: shell

```
2001-06-30T11:33:33,543 DEBUG  (Bss-Thread-948:[]) SUNCA#44#77#CALMED#OK#58#NARDE#4356#68654768961#BHR#TST#DEV
2001-06-30T11:33:33,543 DEBUG  (Bss-Thread-948:[]) SUNCA#44#77#CALMED#OK#58#NARDE#89034#1234567#BHR#TST#DEV
2001-06-30T11:33:33,543 DEBUG  (Bss-Thread-948:[]) SUNCA#44#77#OK#58#BHREDD#234586#4254567#BHR#TST#DEV
2001-06-30T11:33:33,543 DEBUG  (Bss-Thread-948:[]) SUNCA#44#77#OK#58#NARDE#89034#1034567#BHR#TST#DEV
```

I have log file mentioned above. I would like to print lines only if value between patterns # and #BHR is greater than 1100000.

I can see in my log file  lines with values 68654768961, 1234567, 4254567, 1034567. As per the requirement the output should conatin only first 3 lines.

I am looking for regex to get desired output.

Comment: And what did you try yourself? Where’s your starting point in code?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. You should probably also update the title to reflect the fact that your problem needs a column independent solution (just for the future googlers of this issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One questions, this `#58#BHR` should be ignore in third line ? If yes, I will get value between patterns `#` and `#BHR#`.

Normally, it should be solved this question by writing scripting according the business logical. But you could try this one line command by `awk`.

```
awk '{if (0 == system("[ $(echo \"" $0 "\"" " | grep -oP \"" "(?<=#)\\d+(?=#BHR#)\" || echo 0) -gt 1100000 ]")) {print $0}}' log_file
```

Mainly, it use `system()` to scratch the value by `grep`:

```
# if can't get the pattern value by grep, the value will assign 0
echo $one_line | grep -oP "(?<=#)\d+(?=#BHR#)" || echo 0`
```

and compare the value to `1100000` by `[ "$value" -gt 1100000 ]` in `awk`.

FYI, so if the `value` greater than `1100000` it will return `0`.

> system(cmd): executes cmd and returns its exit status

Comment: Thnaks VictorLee. It's working perfectly.